Processor upgrade
I'm upgrading my Ryzen 3200G CPU to a Ryzen 4600G. Does Ubuntu 24.04 require any special configuration for this or will the system automatically recognize it and change the settings if necessary?

Ubuntu will automatically recognize your upgraded processor and change the settings if necessary. To check if the new processor is identified correctly install neofetch (sudo apt install neofetch) and run the command neofetch. Neofetch is a command line script that collects your Linux system information and displays it in the terminal.

Worth noting: only devices using 3rd party drivers need to be removed prior to replacing if those are different brands (graphs card amd vs. nvidia vs intel) and NICs (broadcom vs. intel vs. killer).

Isn't neofetch being deprecated? See this its FOSS article

@graham Neofetch is still available in Ubuntu

@mook765 from the article - "Although it is still available in the repositories of many distributions and will remain for a couple of more releases, I presume."
